# Replacing a set

Tags: replacement

I have the following set

```
{k1\[CenterDot]k1, k2\[CenterDot]k2, 
 k3\[CenterDot]k3, -1 + (k1 - k2)\[CenterDot](k1 - k2), (k2 - 
    k3)\[CenterDot](k2 - k3), (k1 - k3)\[CenterDot](k1 - k3), (k1 - 
    p1)\[CenterDot](k1 - p1), (k1 - p1 - p2)\[CenterDot](k1 - p1 - 
    p2), (k2 - p1 - p2)\[CenterDot](k2 - p1 - p2), (k3 - p1 - 
    p2)\[CenterDot](k3 - p1 - p2), (k2 - p1)\[CenterDot](k2 - 
    p1), (k3 - p1)\[CenterDot](k3 - p1)}
```

Now I want to rewrite this list as

```
{Pr(k1,0),Pr(k2,0),Pr(k3,0),Pr(k1-k2,m),Pr(k2-k3),0),Pr(k1-k3,0),...}
```

The rule is, when it gets `k1\[CenterDot] k1`, it replaces with `Pr(k1,0)` and `k1\[CenterDot] k1-1`, it replaces with `Pr(k1,m)`.

My try for the first step to remove the centerdot,

```
vars = Variables[list];
StringReplace[ToString[list], 
 Table[ToString[vars[[i]]] <> "\[CenterDot]" <> ToString[vars[[i]]] -> 
   ToString[vars[[i]]], {i, Length[vars]}]]
```

But it is not working. How to do this?

Comment: As a comment: 19 questions asked, 0 accepted answers!!!

Comment: I saw your comment. If it is not working then you are not doing something properly. Make sure you copy and paste all the commands as they are and try a fresh kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Commands given below - I had an issue with copy-paste

```
list = {k1\[CenterDot]k1, k2\[CenterDot]k2, 
   k3\[CenterDot]k3, -1 + (k1 - k2)\[CenterDot](k1 - k2), (k2 - 
      k3)\[CenterDot](k2 - k3), (k1 - k3)\[CenterDot](k1 - k3), (k1 - 
      p1)\[CenterDot](k1 - p1), (k1 - p1 - p2)\[CenterDot](k1 - p1 - 
      p2), (k2 - p1 - p2)\[CenterDot](k2 - p1 - p2), (k3 - p1 - 
      p2)\[CenterDot](k3 - p1 - p2), (k2 - p1)\[CenterDot](k2 - 
      p1), (k3 - p1)\[CenterDot](k3 - p1)};
```

we do

```
list /. FullForm[(x_) \[CenterDot] (x_)] :> Pr[x, 0] /. 
  FullForm[(x_) \[CenterDot] ((x_) - 1)] :> Pr[x, m]
```

to get

> {Pr[k1, 0], Pr[k2, 0], Pr[k3, 0], -1 + Pr[k1 - k2, 0], Pr[k2 - k3, 0],
> Pr[k1 - k3, 0], Pr[k1 - p1, 0], Pr[k1 - p1 - p2, 0],
> Pr[k2 - p1 - p2, 0], Pr[k3 - p1 - p2, 0], Pr[k2 - p1, 0],
> Pr[k3 - p1, 0]}

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Pr(k1,0)` is not valid syntax. I assume that you mean `Pr[k1,0]`.
With this we can define a rule:

```
rule= { x_·x_ -> (Pr[x, 0]), ((x_ · x_) - 1) ->  Pr[k1 - k2, m]}
```

and test it:

```
dat = {k1·k1, k2·k2,  k3·k3, -1 + (k1 - k2)·(k1 - k2), (k2 -  k3)·(k2 - k3), (k1 - k3)·(k1 - k3), (k1 - 
      p1)·(k1 - p1), (k1 - p1 - p2)·(k1 - p1 -  p2), (k2 - p1 - p2)·(k2 - p1 - p2), (k3 - p1 - 
      p2)·(k3 - p1 - p2), (k2 - p1)·(k2 -   p1), (k3 - p1)·(k3 - p1)};

dat /. {  x_·x_ -> (Pr[x, 0]), ((x_ · x_) - 1) ->  Pr[k1 - k2, m]}

{Pr[k1, 0], Pr[k2, 0], Pr[k3, 0], Pr[k1 - k2, m], Pr[k2 - k3, 0], 
 Pr[k1 - k3, 0], Pr[k1 - p1, 0], Pr[k1 - p1 - p2, 0], 
 Pr[k2 - p1 - p2, 0], Pr[k3 - p1 - p2, 0], Pr[k2 - p1, 0], 
 Pr[k3 - p1, 0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_ · _] := Pr[x, 0]
f[_] := Pr[k1 - k2, 0] - 1

f /@ list
```

gives the accepted result

{Pr[k1, 0], Pr[k2, 0], Pr[k3, 0], -1 + Pr[k1 - k2, 0], Pr[k2 - k3, 0],
Pr[k1 - k3, 0], Pr[k1 - p1, 0], Pr[k1 - p1 - p2, 0],
Pr[k2 - p1 - p2, 0], Pr[k3 - p1 - p2, 0], Pr[k2 - p1, 0],
Pr[k3 - p1, 0]}